# c# sharpziplib adding file to existing archive

Tags: c#, append, archive, addition, sharpziplib

am trying to add a file to an existing archive using the following code. When run no errors or exceptions are shown but no files are added to the archive either. Any ideas why?

```
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(archivePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (ZipOutputStream zipToWrite = new ZipOutputStream(fileStream))
        {
            zipToWrite.SetLevel(9);

            using (FileStream newFileStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFiles[0]))
            {
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[newFileStream.Length - 1];

                newFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(sourceFiles[0]);
                zipToWrite.PutNextEntry(entry);
                zipToWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                zipToWrite.CloseEntry();

                zipToWrite.Close();
                zipToWrite.Finish();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com), adding files to an existing zip is really simple and reliable.

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFile(additionalFileToAdd);
    zip.Save();
}
```

If you want to specify a directory path for that new file, then use a different overload for AddFile().

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFile(additionalFileToAdd, "directory\\For\\The\\Added\\File");
    zip.Save();
}
```

If you want to add a set of files, use AddFiles().

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(nameOfExistingZip))
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddFiles(listOfFilesToAdd, "directory\\For\\The\\Added\\Files");
    zip.Save();
}
```

You don't have to worry about Close(), CloseEntry(), CommitUpdate(), Finish() or any of that other gunk.

Comment: I'm beginning to hate SharpZipLib, it's too low level and reading the documentation is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

From Codeproject someone used this code. Only difference is close and finish otherway around and the write part:

```
using (ZipOutputStream s = new
ZipOutputStream(File.Create(txtSaveTo.Text + "\\" +
sZipFileName + ".zip")))
{
    s.SetLevel(9); // 0-9, 9 being the highest compression

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    foreach (string file in filenames)
    {

        ZipEntry entry = new
        ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));

        entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        s.PutNextEntry(entry);

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            int sourceBytes;
            do
            {
                sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0,
                buffer.Length);

               s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);

            } while (sourceBytes > 0);
        }
    }
    s.Finish();
    s.Close();
}
```

BTW:

```
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[newFileStream.Length - 1];

                newFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
```

This is incorrect, the size is newFileStream.length else the Read goes wrong.
You have an array and you make it for example 10-1 is 9 bytes long, from 0 to 8.

But your reading from 0 to 9...

Comment: Hi PoweRoy, i have used this code exactly and still no errors but also no file :(

Comment: i have also tried this

            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(archivePath);
            zipFile.BeginUpdate();

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);

            zipFile.Add(fileName);
            zipFile.CommitUpdate();

but then the paths are all wrong. I need to set relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Finish` call should be *before* your `Close` call.

**Update:** This looks like a [known bug](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/7176/20392.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356003/c-sharpziplib-adding-file-to-existing-archive/1356019#1356019aspx#20392). It's possible it may already have been fixed - you'll need to check your SharpZipLib version to see if it incorporates any fix. If not, you can work around it by copying all files to a new archive, adding the new file, then moving the new archive to the old archive name.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 添加压缩文件 p 为客户端传回来的文件/夹列表,用分号隔开，不包括主路径， zipfile压缩包的名称
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p"></param>
    /// <param name="zipfile"></param>
    public void AddZipFile(string p, string zipfile)
    {
        if (ServerDir.LastIndexOf(@"\") != ServerDir.Length - 1)
        {
            ServerDir += @"\";
        }
        string[] tmp = p.Split(new char[] { ';' }); //分离文件列表
        if (zipfile != "") //压缩包名称不为空
        {
            string zipfilepath=ServerDir + zipfile;
            if (_ZipOutputStream == null)
            {
                _ZipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipfilepath));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tmp[i] != "") //分离出来的文件名不为空
                {
                    this.AddZipEntry(tmp[i], _ZipOutputStream, out _ZipOutputStream); //向压缩文件流加入内容
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static ZipOutputStream _ZipOutputStream;
    public void Close()
    {
        _ZipOutputStream.Finish();
        _ZipOutputStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a folder **ZippedFolder** in site's root directory , inside it we have a archive **MyZipFiles**.

There is a folder with name **siteImages** which consists of all image files.
The following is the code to zip the images

```
string zipPath = Server.MapPath("~/ZippedFolder/MyZipFiles.zip");
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
 zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/siteImages/img1.jpg"),string.Empty);
 zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/siteImages/img2.jpg"),string.Empty);
 zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/siteImages/img2.jpg"),string.Empty);
 zip.Save(zipPath);
}
```

if we have different file formats and we want your files to be saved in respective folders,you can specify the code as follows.

```
string zipPath = Server.MapPath("~/ZippedFolder/MyZipFiles.zip");
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/siteimages/img1.jpg"), "images");
  zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/siteimages/img2.jpg"), "images");
  zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/documents/customer.pdf"), "files");
  zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/documents/sample.doc"), "files");
  zip.Save(zipPath);
}
```

now the archive contains two folders
 **images** ---- > img1.jpg , img2,.jpg 
and another folder 
**files** --> customer.pdf, sample.doc

Answer (score 0):

The `ZipOutputStream` class does not update existing ZIP files. Use the `ZipFile` class instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a simple solution keeping it to ZipFile and ZipEntry only

```
        ZipFile zipExisting = ZipFile.Read(Server.MapPath("/_Layouts/includes/Template.zip"));
        ICollection<ZipEntry> entries = _zipFileNew.Entries;
        foreach (ZipEntry zipfile in entries)
        {
            zipExisting.AddEntry(zipfile.FileName, zipfile.InputStream);
        } 

        zipExisting.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
```